# Random entre ciertos numeros

Tags: android-studio, random

Hola quería saber si es posible generar un numero random entre números específicos.
Por ejemplo tengo un tablero de 9 números (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)pero las casillas (2,6,8) ya están ocupadas. Es posible crear un random donde solo puedan salir los números restantes(1,3,4,5,7,9)?

Gracias.

Comment: lo puede hacer con un radom  ,un while y condiones (if),ya lo intentas hacer si ya lo intentaste coloca tu código para poder ayudarte mas fácil

Comment: Puedes guardar los números en una estructura de datos como una lista o un arreglo y obtener un random del largo desde 0 hasta el largo de la lista. Cada vez que encuentras un elemento en la posición obtenida (la posición la determina el random), sacas ese elemento de la lista y sacas un nuevo random con el nuevo largo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Una solución es tener una lista con las posiciones disponibles, "barajarlo" e ir sacando elementos.

```
class Test {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    int[] posiciones = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 };

    shuffleArray(posiciones);
    for (int i = 0; i < posiciones.length; i++) {
      System.out.print(posiciones[i] + " ");
    }
  }

  // Algoritmo Fisher–Yates para barajar
  static void shuffleArray(int[] ar) {

    Random rnd = ThreadLocalRandom.current();
    for (int i = ar.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
      int index = rnd.nextInt(i + 1);
      int a = ar[index];
      ar[index] = ar[i];
      ar[i] = a;
    }
  }
}
```