# hacer un random de string, el cual me vaya seleccionando los siguientes resultados obviando los que ya se obtuvieron

Tags: java, random

Me han pedido hacer un programa el cual me haga preguntas random las cuales se responderan verdadero o falso; mi problema esta en que se hacer un string para esto, pero, no se hacer que el random no me repita las preguntas que ya me hizo anteriormente

el codigo seria algo asi

creo el vector

```
  String [] array = {"A", "B", "C", "D"};
     Random random = new Random();
```

para seleccionar un indice random del vector

```
int R = random.nextInt(array.length);
```

Comment: crea un array secundario y ve metiendo los valores que ya te salieron, y  cuando haga el random compara si ya existe en el arreglo

Comment: Dos opciones: A) Usas una lista dinámica (p.ej. `java.util.ArrayList` de donde puedes eliminar los valores usados, y haces que el random dependa del número de elementos restantes, o bien B) marcas las preguntas que ya han salido (p.ej las pones a `null`) y si escoges una que ya ha salido obtienes un nuevo random.

Comment: un algoritmo de barajar (shuffle) lo podes ver en https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/118231/random-entre-ciertos-numeros/118241#118241, y el thread en inglish https://stackoverflow.com/a/1520212/1423096 tiene otras alternativas

Comment: Para no perder tus valores, puedes añadir un símbolo al principio o final de la frase una vez que la hayas preguntado. También podrías crear una clase que contenga el String y un boolean para indicar si se ha mostrado ya o no esa pregunta

Answer (score 3):

```
String extraerUnElemento(List<String> preguntas) {
    if (preguntas.size() == 0) return null;
    Collections.shuffle(preguntas);
    return preguntas.remove(0);
}
```

**`size()`** retorna la cantidad de elementos de la lista.

**`shuffle()`** mezcla los elementos de la lista

**`remove(int indice)`** extrae el elemento posicionado en el indice y lo retorna

Comment: las respuestas que son solo código se consideran de baja calidad, toda vez que no explicas nada de lo que hace este script

Comment: @shadow crei que no era necesario, la api es bastante descriptiva. De todas maneras edito.

Comment: es totalmente necesario aqui va a consultar muchisima gente y no todos tienen conocimientos o experiencia entonces siempre debe ser código y explicación

Answer (score 1):

Aquí lo importante es utilizar el [Collection.shuffle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) para desordenar la lista, también creé un DTO llamado PreguntaRespuestaDTO, lo que primero hago es generar la lista con las preguntas(PreguntaRespuestaDTO), para luego iterar sobre la lista y obtener un elemento random a la vez, para después eliminar de la lista el elemento random que ya obtuve y **no se repita**.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<PreguntaRespuestaDTO> preguntas = new ArrayList<PreguntaRespuestaDTO>();


        PreguntaRespuestaDTO preguntaRespuestaDTOA = new PreguntaRespuestaDTO();
        preguntaRespuestaDTOA.setNoPregunta("A");
        preguntaRespuestaDTOA.setPregunta("¿Actaulmente estas trabajando?");
        preguntas.add(preguntaRespuestaDTOA);

        PreguntaRespuestaDTO preguntaRespuestaDTOB = new PreguntaRespuestaDTO();
        preguntaRespuestaDTOB.setNoPregunta("B");
        preguntaRespuestaDTOB.setPregunta("¿Tienes auto?");
        preguntas.add(preguntaRespuestaDTOB);

        PreguntaRespuestaDTO preguntaRespuestaDTOC = new PreguntaRespuestaDTO();
        preguntaRespuestaDTOC.setNoPregunta("C");
        preguntaRespuestaDTOC.setPregunta("¿Tienes casa propia?");
        preguntas.add(preguntaRespuestaDTOC);

        PreguntaRespuestaDTO preguntaRespuestaDTOD = new PreguntaRespuestaDTO();
        preguntaRespuestaDTOD.setNoPregunta("D");
        preguntaRespuestaDTOD.setPregunta("¿Eres casado?");
        preguntas.add(preguntaRespuestaDTOD);

        PreguntaRespuestaDTO preguntaRespuestaDTOE = new PreguntaRespuestaDTO();
        preguntaRespuestaDTOE.setNoPregunta("E");
        preguntaRespuestaDTOE.setPregunta("¿Tienes hijos?");
        preguntas.add(preguntaRespuestaDTOE);


        List<PreguntaRespuestaDTO> listaReducida = preguntas;
        PreguntaRespuestaDTO preguntaRandom = null;

        for(int indice= 0; indice<preguntas.size(); indice++){
            //Se obtiene una pregunta random
            preguntaRandom = Test.obtenerRespuestaRandom(listaReducida);
            //Se elimina ese elemnto de la lista el elemento random que se obtuvo
            listaReducida = Test.obtenerListaReducida(listaReducida,preguntaRandom);
            //Se imprime la pregunta
            System.out.println(preguntaRandom.getNoPregunta()+"   "+preguntaRandom.getPregunta());
        }

    }

    public static PreguntaRespuestaDTO obtenerRespuestaRandom(List<PreguntaRespuestaDTO> preguntas){
        Random randomGenerator = new Random();
        //Se genera el random
        int index = randomGenerator.nextInt(preguntas.size());
        if (preguntas.size() == 0) return null;
        //Se desordena la lista
        Collections.shuffle(preguntas);
        //se obtiene el indice de la lista
        PreguntaRespuestaDTO preguntaRespuestaDTO = preguntas.get(index);
        return preguntaRespuestaDTO;
    }
    public static List<PreguntaRespuestaDTO> obtenerListaReducida(List<PreguntaRespuestaDTO> listaReducida, PreguntaRespuestaDTO preguntaAEliminar){
        List<PreguntaRespuestaDTO> nuevaLista = new ArrayList<PreguntaRespuestaDTO>();
        for(PreguntaRespuestaDTO pregunta:listaReducida){
            //Solo se agregan a la nueva lista los demás elementos 
            if(!pregunta.getNoPregunta().equals(preguntaAEliminar.getNoPregunta())){
                nuevaLista.add(pregunta);
            }
        }
        return nuevaLista;
    }
}

    class PreguntaRespuestaDTO {
        private String noPregunta;
        private String pregunta;
        private boolean respuesta;

        /**
         * @return the noPregunta
         */
        public String getNoPregunta() {
            return noPregunta;
        }

        /**
         * @param noPregunta
         *            the noPregunta to set
         */
        public void setNoPregunta(String noPregunta) {
            this.noPregunta = noPregunta;
        }

        /**
         * @return the pregunta
         */
        public String getPregunta() {
            return pregunta;
        }

        /**
         * @param pregunta
         *            the pregunta to set
         */
        public void setPregunta(String pregunta) {
            this.pregunta = pregunta;
        }

        /**
         * @return the respuesta
         */
        public boolean isRespuesta() {
            return respuesta;
        }

        /**
         * @param respuesta
         *            the respuesta to set
         */
        public void setRespuesta(boolean respuesta) {
            this.respuesta = respuesta;
        }
    }
```

Este es el resultado:

E   ¿Tienes hijos?

C   ¿Tienes casa propia?

B   ¿Tienes auto?

D   ¿Eres casado?

A   ¿Actaulmente estas trabajando?

***Nota: Cada vez que se ejecuta regresa las preguntas en diferente orden.***

Comment: muchas gracias por la respuesta